# gnuplot - draw stacked line chart

Tags: charts, gnuplot, histogram

I work with in-house benchmark tool. I use **gnuplot** (`gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 4`) for visualization.

I need to represent results (method execution times for several runs) as stacked line chart, something like this:

[image: example stacked line chart]

Here is an excerpt from my `.tsv` data file:

```
Run MethodA MethodB MethodC 
1   192 171 152
2   227 178 161
...
10  229 161 149
```

And the script I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p

reset
clear

set terminal png size 640,480
set output "timings.png"
set key top left outside horizontal autotitle columnhead
set title "Third-party REST calls"

set xlabel "Run (ordinal)"
set xtics nomirror scale 0

set ylabel "Time (milliseconds)"
set ytics out nomirror

set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#bbbbbb"

set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75

plot  "timings.tsv" using 2:xticlabels(1) , "" using 3, "" using 4
```

I get the following result:

[image: histogram]

Yes, it's not a line chart but histogram (I need to represent percentage of execution time of each method). I need slightly different result (the same histogram, not with boxes but with lines which connect boxes tops and with filling below lines), like this:

[image: stacked line diagram - desired diagram]

I'm aware of approach with `filledcurve`'s (for instance, described there [Creating a Filled Stack Graph in GNUPlot](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/creating-a-filled-stack-graph-in-gnuplot/)), but in that approach you need to sum values explicitly.

Is it possible to draw filled areas instead of boxes via `gnuplot`, e.g. convert histogram into stacked line chart?

Comment: Yes, you must sum explicitely, but that is quite easy using `plot for` together with the `sum` function, like in that page you linked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to sum values explicitly, but this is not a big issue. You can script it easily:

```
firstcol=2
cumulated(i)=((i>firstcol)?column(i)+cumulated(i-1):(i==firstcol)?column(i):1/0)
plot "file.dat" using 1:(cumulated(4)), "" using 1:(cumulated(3)), "" using 1:(cumulated(2))
```

Comment: It works not only for 3 data columns. I've also successfully summed 6 columns. The only downside of `... using 1:(cumulated(4)), "" using 1:(cumulated(3)) ...` is that columns titles disappear. So the legend gets missed. But it's not hard to recover it, just add title for each column like this: `... using 1:(cumulated(4)) title columnhead(4), "" using 1:(cumulated(3)) title columnhead(3) ...` Thank you very much.

Comment: It does work for any column number, and `firstcol` allows you to define the first column of the sequence to sum. It would be a little more awkward to skip some columns, though. Using the reverse order can be useful in combination with `filledcurve`.